# Condition inside a Where clause in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure. In that where condition, I want to select the not null value if there are any, else select the null value from the table. Anyone Kindly help me..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SearchPromotionBYPromotionANDVehicleID

@PromotionCode VARCHAR(100)
,@TypeId INT
,@LocationId INT
,@ClientId INT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


SELECT top 1 tp.PromotionID
    ,tp.PromotionCode
    ,tp.ClientID
    ,tp.StartDate
    ,tp.EndDate
    ,tp.VehicleTypeId
    ,tv.VehicleType
    ,tp.LocationId

FROM tblstudent tp
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblType tv ON tp.TypeId = tv.TypeId
WHERE tp.PromotionCode = @PromotionCode

    AND
     ( ( @LocationId IS NOT NULL AND tp.LocationId = @LocationId ) OR (tp.LocationId IS NULL) OR (@LocationId IS NULL) or (tp.LocationId = 0 ) )
```

In this consider 2 records (r1 and r2) with same promotion code and one with all locations (that is location id 0) and another with a location ID. When the parameter @locationId have a value(consider the value equal to the value of the record r2) then it have to return the record 2. Else have to return r1.

Comment: The problem is when I add a record with a locationID1, and then with 0 locationID2, and another with another location ID, when I want to select locationID2, the record with locationId 0 is returning

Comment: Instead of describing your sample data in words, use DDL + DML for it. That way, we can copy it to a test environment and give you an accurate answer. Also, please add the tags for the relevant RDBMS you are using (product tag as well as version tag).

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE tp.PromotionCode = @PromotionCode
AND (( @LocationId IS NOT NULL AND tp.LocationId = @LocationId ) OR tp.LocationId IS NULL)
```

This condition selects those values where *@LocationId* has a not null and not 0 value, And the value needs to match with *tp.LocationId*, Otherwise it returns those where *tp.LocationId* is null.
Is it the result what you want? If you want different, let me know